# Python - checking for vowels, code returns false no matter what

Tags: python

I am a beginner, so I apologize if this question seems too simple. I don't know where to go from here with my code, so that it works correctly. Any suggestions on where to go from here would be very much appreciated!

Thank you.

```
def isVowel(word, i):
for i in word:
    if i == 'a' or i == 'e' or i == 'i' or i == 'o' or i =='u' or i == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

this is how i planned on executing it:

```
[isVowel('detestable', i) for i in range(len('detestable'))]
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

as you can see, I continue to get false as the result. I have tried a few different things, and I keep getting all false or all true.

#### UPDATE

I thought I had already tried this, but

```
def isVowel(word, i):
    if word[i] == 'a' or word[i] == 'e' or word[i] == 'i' or word[i] == 'o' or word[i] =='u' or word[i] == 'y':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

works perfectly. Feel free to continue to add suggestions, as I'm sure there are more effective ways to write this code.

Comment: Notice what happens in the function `isVowel`. The for-loop is meant to look through all of the characters in `word` one at a time. **But** when `i` is set to the first character in word `i` is either a vowel or it is not a vowel, which means that the function will **immediately** return either `True` or `False`. The rest of the characters are never evaluated.

Comment: are you checking if a letter is a vowel or checking if a word has a vowel?

Comment: Please use the answer box below to post the solution that worked for you, and edit the solution out of the question. We like to keep questions and answers separate, so users can vote on them individually.

Answer (score 0):

From the usage example, it seems as though `isVowel` should only evaluate a single character, not a word:

```
def isVowel(i):
    return i in 'aeiou'
```

And in practice:

```
>>> [isVowel(i) for i in 'detestable']
[False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post the same as @Mureinik.

Here's a little different version.

```
>>> is_vowel = lambda v: v in 'aeiou'
>>> word = 'detestable'
>>> [is_vowel(ch) for ch in word]
[False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, False, True]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

So my interpretation is you want to get a list of booleans for every letter if it is one of these letters `aeiuoy`:

```
def is_vowel(word):
    return [letter in 'aeiuoy' for letter in word]
```

used like that:

```
is_vowel('foobar')
-> [False, True, True, False, True, False]
```

so my recommendation for you would be to check out the i in the function `isVowel(word, i):` because it is actually overwritten by usage of i the for loop `for i in word:`. And I would recommend freshing up your knowledge about functions and scopes in python + python list comprehensions.